# What is a " AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'replace' " in python?

Tags: python, attributes

```
print (
"""    Welcome to the code breaker game!
       In this game you will have to change symbols into letters in order to decipher secret words. 
       0 - instructions
       1 - start
       2 - clues
       3 - check your answers
       4 - quit
""")

choice = input(" choice : ")

if choice == ("0"):
    text_file = open ("instructions.txt","r")
    print (text_file.read())
    text_file.close()

elif choice =="1":
    text_file = open ("words.txt","r")
    contents = text_file
    print (text_file.read())
    text_file.close()
    a = input("Please enter a symbol ")
    b = input("Please enter a letter ")

    newcontents = contents.replace(a,b)
    contents = newcontents
    print(contents,"\n")
    text_file.close


elif choice == "2":
 text_file = open ("clues.txt","r")
 print (text_file.read())
 text_file.close()

elif choice == "3":
 text_file = open ("solved.txt","r")
 print (text_file.read())
 text_file.close()

elif choice == "4":
 quit
```

So basically I'm doing a computer science project and my task is to make a decoding game by substituting symbols to letters but I get this error for when I try to make the part of the code which actually changes symbols into letters.

Also is there any way to make this loop (not using `while` loops as they are quite complicated)? I basically want the code to show me the A and B when I run the program and for me after choosing any option to be able to choose a different option. (Eg I press 0 for instructions and then be able to choose a different option such as start game).

Comment: What you actually need to do is take the text from the file, do what you want with it and then finally rewrite that data.

Comment: The error is: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\server2.school.local\pupils$\11.jakub\year 10\Computer science\Computer science project\Year 10 Computer science project\Code 2014\NEWPYTHONCODE.py", line 26, in <module>
    newcontents = contents.replace(a,b)
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: I can't as the project specification says I have to use the provided .txts file's

Comment: Your sub-question duplicates e.g. [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18791882/python-how-to-make-program-go-back-to-the-top-of-the-code-instead-of-closing). Just use a `while` loop; they aren't that complicated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This part of your code:

```
text_file = open ("words.txt","r")
contents = text_file
print (text_file.read())
text_file.close()
```

makes no sense. You are assigning the file object (*not* the file's contents) to `contents`. You then `print` the contents, but don't assign them to anything. I think what you want is:

```
with open("words.txt") as text_file:
    contents = text_file.read()
print(contents)
```

Comment: Ok this helped a lot as it prints the coded words now with the changes but it won't ask me for a new pairing of a symbol to letter substitute,do you know how I could do that?

Comment: @user3661051 see my comment on the question. There are numerous duplicates on SO.