# Return to the top after results

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently experimenting on different ways to solve exponents(via addition). As soon as the results are printed, I could not use the program anymore.

I've tried *continue* and *break*, but they're not appropriate

```
x = int(input())
y = 0
z = x
while z != 0:
    y += x
    z -= 1
    if z <= 0:
        y *= x
print(y)
```

I just need to re-use the application again after the previous results, and keep using it until it is closed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make program go back to the top of the code instead of closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18791882/how-to-make-program-go-back-to-the-top-of-the-code-instead-of-closing)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to wrap everything in a while loop and give some type of exit condition.

```
x = input()
while x != 'exit':
    x = int(x)
    y = 0
    z = x
    while z != 0:
        y += x
        z -= 1
        if z <= 0:
            y *= x
    print(y)
    x = int(input())

print('You chose to end the program, goodbye!')
```