# How can I implement a function/loop in a cmd game?

Tags: python, function, loops, cmd

I've started to make a cmd-based minigame, and I wanna implement a feature, where you come across choices which you have to decide that what option will you choose. My problem however is that in my code, if you type anything other than the two options listed, than the game will just 'end' there.

```
print('Welcome to \'The Exchange\'.')
print('This game is all about making wise decisions with your money.')
print('At the beginning, you\'ll start out with 10$, and from here,')
print('Everything is YOUR choice! Have fun!\n')

# Starter informations. #
yourMoney = 100

# First choise part of the game. #
print('You\'ve come to your first decision of the game -')
print('Do you want to make an insurance for 5 dollars, or you just wanna skip it for now?')
firstDecision = input('Type \"make\" to make one, and \"skip\" to just skip it.\n')

if(firstDecision == "make"):
    print("Fine.")
elif(firstDecision == "skip"):
    print("Not fine.")
else:
    print("You've misspelled it, try again!")
```

But I want to make it that if you type anything other than the two options, then the game would simply ask the question again, and again, until you type any of the two optins, and then, it would move on. I know, that I have to use some kind of loop, or function, and I also tried these in my code, but it haven't turned out too great. I'd greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: Many similar questions have already been asked [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20337489/python-how-to-keep-repeating-a-program-until-a-specific-input-is-obtained) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18791882/how-to-make-program-go-back-to-the-top-of-the-code-instead-of-closing?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion with minimal change in the code.

```py
print('Welcome to \'The Exchange\'.')
print('This game is all about making wise decisions with your money.')
print('At the beginning, you\'ll start out with 10$, and from here,')
print('Everything is YOUR choice! Have fun!\n')

# Starter informations. #
yourMoney = 100

# First choise part of the game. #
print('You\'ve come to your first decision of the game -')
print('Do you want to make an insurance for 5 dollars, or you just wanna skip it for now?')
firstDecision = input('Type \"make\" to make one, and \"skip\" to just skip it.\n')

while(firstDecision != 'make' or  firstDecision != 'skip'):
    if(firstDecision == "make"):
        print("Fine.")

        ### Do here all your logics and in the end add the line below
        break

    elif(firstDecision == "skip"):
        print("Not fine.")

        ### Do here all your logics and in the end add the line below
        break        
    else:
        print("You've misspelled it, try again!")
        firstDecision = input('Type \"make\" to make one, and \"skip\" to just skip it.\n')
```

Please let me know if there were problems or this is not what you wanted.